# "error: 'ptrdiff_t' does not name a type" on installing Berkley DB XML 2.5.16 in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-12.04, vagrant, berkeley-db-xml

An error is received when running the build script for Berkley DB XML 2.5.16 in Ubuntu 12.04 with vagrant on a virtualbox:

```
../include/xqilla/framework/XPath2MemoryManager.hpp:90:11: error: 'ptrdiff_t' does not name a type
make[1]: *** [ReferenceCounted.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/share/dbxml-2.5.16/xqilla/build'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolution was to add the following line after line 26 to the file XPath2MemoryManager.hpp:

```
#include <cstddef>
```

The full path to the file is:

```
/usr/share/dbxml-2.5.16/xqilla/include/xqilla/framework/XPath2MemoryManager.hpp
```

Credit to http://tlmaloney.ruhoh.com/sysadmin/installing-bdb-xml-in-ubuntu/